# Hide navigation when at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello how can i hide my navigation when not scrolling and show it when i scroll

i am using two menus at this link `http://dev.thegabrielmethod.com/gabriel/`

one on a white bg and the other on a blue bg

i would like to hide the navigation menu items on the white bg when not scrolling and then show them again when scrolling

[image]

This is what am trying which is not working

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
        var headerTop = $('#header').offset().top;
        var headerBottom = headerTop + 120; // Sub-menu should appear after this distance from top.
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // Current vertical scroll position from the top
            if (scrollTop > headerBottom) { // Check to see if we have scrolled more than headerBottom
                if (($("#navigation-alongside").is(":visible") === false)) {
                    $('#navigation-alongside').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            } else {
                if ($("#navigation-alongside").is(":visible")) {
                    $('#navigation-alongside').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Please some one advice

Comment: But you're only showing it once you have scrolled past it (so it will be off the page)?  What happens if the page is not big enough to scroll, you never show the header nav?  That seems a bit daft

Comment: i knw wat am doin might be daft, can you show me a better way based on the class for that navigation thanks

Comment: i just need to hide the navigation when not scrolling and show when scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Observed your html as well. and found some issue. first is - 
you have set the margin for `blue` nav bar - `margin-top: 100px;` that is not required.

and the execute the below code.

open that site, and open developer tool > in console execute the below code, then scroll the page, you will see its working as expected.

You just need to execute the below code on page load, and it will handle the margin issue as well in second line..

```
jQuery('.banner.include-nav').fadeOut();
jQuery('.nav-bar-below.op-page-header.cf').css({'margin':'0px'});
var h = jQuery('.nav-bar-below.op-page-header.cf').height();
jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > h)
    {
        jQuery('.banner.include-nav').fadeIn();
    }
    else 
    {
        jQuery('.banner.include-nav').fadeOut();
    }
})
```

**Before Scroll**

[image]

**When Scroll**

[image]

**Update**

As per you comment I understood you, in white one you just wanted to hide the menu not the logo itself. try the below code. as told you above now.

```
jQuery('.banner.include-nav > .fixed-width.cf > .sixteen.columns').fadeOut();
//jQuery('.nav-bar-below.op-page-header.cf').css({'margin':'0px'});
var h = jQuery('.nav-bar-below.op-page-header.cf').height();
jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > h)
    {
        jQuery('.banner.include-nav > .fixed-width.cf > .sixteen.columns').fadeIn();
    }
    else 
    {
        jQuery('.banner.include-nav > .fixed-width.cf > .sixteen.columns').fadeOut();
    }
})
```

Comment: i need the white background logo minus the navigation and the blue bg below when not scrolling

Comment: did you try the one I gave to you above?? if yes then what change you need in this??

Comment: ok, look at the link again prsently the only am trying to do is remv d navigation on the white bg when not scrolling, the present one based on your screenshot will remove d nav and white banner using this class .banner.include-nav , but this what am trying to target #navigation-alongside the id of the menu on the white bg

Comment: updated the answer. try the new code, it will hide/show only menu of white nav bar.

Comment: this is the id of the menu i want to hide when not scrolling and show when scrolling #navigation-alongside

Comment: yes I will post the image as well. hold on.  remember I m testing on -
`http://dev.thegabrielmethod.com/gabriel/`    check the links and read the comment in link as well. `https://ibb.co/kabbDv`, 
`https://ibb.co/gVBnLa`,  
`https://ibb.co/h2pwDv`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139739/discussion-between-deepak-sharma-and-tee-famakin).

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".menu").css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
      $(".menu").css({
        'display': 'block'
      });
    }, 100));
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 2mm 10px #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  padding: 0px !important;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="menu"><br/>
    <h1>Menu Box</h1>
  </div>

</body>
```

Here! 
It won't show the menu while scrolling.. and will show it again when when scrolling finished.

Please inform if I have misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    topMenu = document.querySelector('.banner.include-nav');
    scrollTopAmount = document.body.scrollTop;

    if (scrollTopAmount != 0) {
        topMenu.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
        topMeny.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks it didnt work, appreciate and this is the id of the menu #navigation-alongside

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will resolve your issue

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
if(scroll==0){
 jQuery('.include-nav').hide();
  jQuery('.nav-bar-below.op-page-header').css('margin-top','0px');
}else{
  jQuery('.include-nav').show();
  jQuery('.nav-bar-below.op-page-header').css('margin-top','100px');
}
});
```

Comment: no this dosent work sir, thank u for replying though, what am trying to do sir is when not scrolling the menu bar on the white banner disappears, and when scrolling the menu comes back. http://dev.thegabrielmethod.com/gabriel/

Comment: If try to paste same code in console of your browser, it should work. It works fine for me

Comment: can we skype pls, cuz i applied it and it didnt work for me

Comment: whats your skype id ?